# How to extract arrays out of another array in PHP

Tags: php, loops, foreach, hashmap

I have an array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [filePath] => 0000000023.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Label] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Person
                            [1] => Person
                        )

                    [Score] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 0.999217033
                            [1] => 0.999318361
                        )

                    [Coordinates] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 338
                                    [1] => 430
                                    [2] => 307
                                    [3] => 506
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 71
                                    [1] => 104
                                    [2] => 318
                                    [3] => 483
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I need to make it to be look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [filePath] => 0000000023.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Label] => Person
                    [Score] => 0.999217033
                    [Coordinates] => 
                        [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 338
                                    [1] => 430
                                    [2] => 307
                                    [3] => 506
                                )
                )
            [1] => Array                     
                (
                    [Label] => Person
                    [Score] => 0.999318361
                    [Coordinates] => 
                        [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 71
                                    [1] => 104
                                    [2] => 318
                                    [3] => 483
                                )
                )

        )

)
```

In Ruby I can use map and select to get the result however in PHP I can't figure it out. I managed to do it with `Foreach` loop however it is very ugly and lots of if statement.

I'd appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done with foreach, but no IF's. I think it's not useful to use PHP mapping or other array functions for such thing (although)

Check this:

```
$tab = [
    [
        'filePath' => '0000000023.jpg'
    ],
    [
        [
            'Label' => [
                'Person',
                'Person'
            ],
            'Score' => [
                0.999217033,
                0.999318361
            ],
            'Coordinates' => [
                [338, 430, 307, 506],
                [71, 104, 318, 483]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

$returnTab[0] = $tab[0];

foreach ($tab[1][0]['Label'] as $pos => $label) {
    $returnTab[1][] = [
        'Label' => $label,
        'Score' => $tab[1][0]['Score'][$pos],
        'Coordinates' => $tab[1][0]['Coordinates'][$pos],
    ];
}
var_dump($returnTab);
```

Comment: Nice. Good solution. Thanks mate. Not sure why I got -2 vote!!!

Comment: Probably because it is a very specific problem. It does not help others too much.

Comment: Now, Stackoverflow doesn't let me to remove the question either.

Answer (score -1):

Why extract array ? You can not create directly your array like this ?

Multidimensional php array are very ugly. You can not use a collection of object ?

Comment: The original array is supplied from another source. I get the Array that I mentioned, then I need to consume it so if I can create a cleaner array with good key value pair then I can parse it and feed it to DB or Redis.